# Use django-filter info in the OPTIONS method with django-restframework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I use `django-filter` with `django-restframework` as explained [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#api-guide). This is a very convenient way to implement filters for a list api for instance.

One of django-restframework's biggest strength is the natural documentation provided by the http method `OPTIONS`. For `PUT` and `POST` calls, it gives you easily the required format of the body (required fields, their format, choices sometimes etc). The communication between the api developers and the clients is improved since it's easy to make an `OPTIONS` call and it's still up-to-date.

**Is it possible to use the filters defined with parameters `filter_fields` and/or `filter_class` to improve the output of the `OPTIONS` call**? Ideally, this call should provide:

- The list of available filters
- Their types
- The choices if there are

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it's not possible out of the box.
You could possibly redefine your own meta classe for options and set it in your view `metadata_class`.

The default metadata class entry point is:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/metadata.py#L62